# jQuery: Problem assigning setIntervals to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm attempting to run multiple animations (slideshows of sorts) on one page, but the code is only working for one of the (in my case) 3 slideshows that are actually present.

The issue is not with the animation but with the actual initialisation and running of functions (explained better below by looking at the code):

The HTML:

```
<div class="someclass1" rel="slideshow" type="fade" duration=8500>
  <div class="wrapper">...</div>
  <div class="wrapper">...</div>
</div>
<div class="someclass2" rel="slideshow" type="slide" duration=4000>
  <div class="wrapper">...</div>
  <div class="wrapper">...</div>
</div>
<div class="someclass3" rel="slideshow" type="fade" duration=5000>
  <div class="wrapper">...</div>
  <div class="wrapper">...</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var plays = [];
    var duration = 0;
    var targets = [];
    var t = "";
    var $obs = $('div[rel="slideshow"]')
    for(var x = 0; x < $obs.length; x++){
        $obs.eq(x).children('.wrapper').eq(0).addClass('active');
        $obs.eq(x).children('.wrapper').css({opacity: 0.0});
        $obs.eq(x).children('.active').css({opacity: 1.0});
        $obs.eq(x).children('.navigation a.slide-buttons').eq(0).addClass('current');

        // Set duration
        duration = $obs.eq(x).attr('duration');

        // Set target
        targets = $obs.eq(x).attr('class').split(' ');
        t = '';
        for(var i=0; i<targets.length; i++){
            t += '.' + targets[i];
        }

        if($obs.eq(x).attr('type')==='fade'){
            plays[x] = setInterval(function(){fadeSwitch(t);}, duration);
        }
        else if($obs.eq(x).attr('type')==='slide'){
            plays[x] = setInterval(function(){slideSwitch(t);}, duration);
        }
     }
});
```

Through testing, I have shown that the loop runs successfully and passes the appropriate target and duration to either fadeSwitch or slideSwitch for all 3 runs of the loop.

fadeSwitch and slideSwitch are identical except for the animation part, for example:

```
function fadeSwitch(target) {
var $active = $(target+' .active');
if ( $active.length === 0 ){ $active = $(target+' .wrapper:first');}

var $next = $active.next('.wrapper').length ? $active.next('.wrapper')
    : $(target+' .wrapper:first');

// FADE ANIMATIONS
$active.animate({opacity : 0.0}, 500, function() {
    $active.addClass('last-active');
});
$next.animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500, function() {
    $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    $next.addClass('active');
});
}
```

However this function will run only using the last found target (i.e t = '.someClass3'). Even though by placing console.log alerts in the setInterval functions I know that it is applying the correct variables.

e.g.

```
plays[0] = setInterval(function(){fadeSwitch('.someclass1');}, 8500);
plays[1] = setInterval(function(){fadeSwitch('.someclass2');}, 4000);
plays[2] = setInterval(function(){fadeSwitch('.someclass3');}, 5000);
```

Yet as I have tried to (badly) explain, if I place a console.log inside of fadeSwitch to test what is being passed as the target when it runs (remember it is set to run after an interval, so by the time the .someClass1 function runs for the first time, the plays[] array is full and finished) the log shows that the target is always .someClass3 and it never succesfully runs for anything else but that last entered target.

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `t` is  being "closed over" by your anonymous functions when you call `setInterval`. For every iteration of your loop you create a new anonymous function, and like you said, at the time `t` has the right value.

The problem is that by the time each function executes `t`'s value has changed (it will hold the last value of the loops), and all three anonymous functions refer to the same t variable (that is the nature of a closure and the lexical scoping of javascript). The quick fix is to give each anonymous function the right *value* and not a reference to t:

Change this:

```
plays[x] = setInterval(function(){fadeSwitch(t);}, duration);
```

to this:

```
plays[x] = setInterval((function(t2){ return function(){ fadeSwitch(t2); }; })(t), duration);
```

And obviously the same for the same line with `slideSwitch`.

Another thing I felt I should point out: You're using invalid attributes in your html, consider finding an alternative, like hidden embedded markup (e.g. `<div class="duration" style="display:none">5000</div>`), or class names, or html5 data attributes, instead of `<div duration=5000>`